# Bash script with `set -e` doesn't stop on `... && ...` command

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I use `set -e` to [stop bash script on first error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870992/automatic-exit-from-bash-shell-script-on-error).

All work OK unless I use command with `&&`:

```
$ cat script
set -e
cd not_existing_dir && echo 123
echo "I'm running! =P"
$
$ ./script
./script: line 2: cd: not_existing_dir: No such file or directory
I'm running! =P
$
```

compared with:

```
$ cat script
set -e
cd not_existing_dir
echo "I'm running! =P"
$
$ ./script
./script: line 2: cd: not_existing_dir: No such file or directory
$
```

The first example still echoes `I'm running!`, but the second one doesn't. Why do they behave differently?

UPD. Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930295/set-e-and-short-tests

Comment: What do you expect to happen in the first example?

Comment: @Flup I expect script to stop after unsuccessful `cd` command

Comment: See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) for a general discussion of places where `set -e` behavior is surprising.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794905/why-does-set-e-true-false-true-not-exit

Comment: look into `set -eu -o pipefail`  specifically `pipefail`.

Comment: @RichardTylerMiles `pipefail` won't help. It works for pipes (`|`) and not for AND/OR

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is documented behavior. 
The [bash(1) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) says, for **`set -e`**,

> The shell does not exit if the command that fails
>   is part of the command list
>   immediately following a `while` or `until` keyword,
>   part of the test following the `if` or `elif` reserved words,
>   ***part of any command executed in a `&&` or `||` list***
>   except the command following the final `&&` or `||`,
>   any command in a pipeline but the last,
>   or if the command's return value is being inverted with `!`.
>   [Emphasis added.]

And the [POSIX *Shell Command Language* Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set)
confirms that this is the correct behavior:

> The `-e` setting shall be ignored
>   when executing the compound list
>   following the `while`, `until`,`if`, or `elif` reserved word,
>   a pipeline beginning with the `!` reserved word,
>   or any command of an AND-OR list other than the last.

and [Section 2.9.3 *Lists*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03) of that document defines

> An AND-OR list is a sequence of one or more pipelines
>   separated by the operators "`&&`" and "`||`" .

Answer (score 12):

The `set -e` option doesn't have effect in some situations, and this is the standard behavior and portable across POSIX compliant shell.

---

The failed command is part of pipeline:

```
false | true; echo printed
```

will print `printed`.

And only the failure of the pipeline itself is considered:

```
true | false; echo 'not printed'
```

will print nothing.

---

The failed command run in the compound list following the `while`, `until`, `if`, `elif` reserved word, a pipeline beginning with the `!` reserved word, or any command as part of `&&` or `||` list except the last one:

```
false || true; echo printed
```

The last command fails still make `set -e` affected:

```
true && false; echo 'not printed'
```

---

The *subshell* fails in a compound command:

```
(false; echo 'not printed') | cat -; echo printed
```

Comment: Thank you! It would be clearer to use `echo "printed"` and `echo "not_printed"` in your examples (instead of `echo 1`).

Comment: Note that `set -e` causes an exit in `(false && true); echo not here`, but not in `{ false && true; }; echo here`, though YMMV with different shells and even different versions of a same shell. I wouldn't  touch `set -e` with a barge pole and would do proper error handling instead.

Answer (score 2):

my guess is if-then condition as a whole evaluate to true.

I tried

```
set -e
if cd not_existing_dir
then  echo 123
fi
echo "I'm running! =P"
```

who give

```
-bash: cd: not_existing_dir: No such file or directory
I'm running! =P
```

error code is catch by if condition, thus bash will not trigger end of execution.

Comment: But I do not use `if ... fi`

Comment: I know, this is an implicit if.