# Why does `source foo && true` exit the script in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

So, I've read this:
[Bash script with `set -e` doesn't stop on `... && ...` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312631/bash-script-with-set-e-doesnt-stop-on-command)

It makes sense. So now, the question:

Test A:

```
$ cat ./test.sh 

set -ex
source foo && true
echo 'running'

$ ./test.sh 
++ source foo
./test.sh: line 16: foo: No such file or directory

$ echo $?
1
```

Test B:

```
$ cat ./test.sh 

set -ex
cat foo && true
echo 'running'

$ ./test.sh 
++ cat foo
cat: foo: No such file or directory
++ echo running
running

$ echo $?
0
```

Why is `source` uniquely violating this rule (**bold**)?

> The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test following the if or elif reserved words, **part of any command executed in a && or || list except the command following the final &&** or ||, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command's return value is being inverted with !.

Comment: You need to be more careful. You are running your scripts with `sh` not `bash`.

Comment: @Fólkvangr, it fails on Darwin, and on Linux.

Comment: @meuh it doesn't matter. it fails with /bin/bash and /bin/sh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`source` is an alias to the dot `.` command and the dot command is a so called `special command` where POSIX describes that these commands exit the whole non-interactive shell in case that an error occurs.

If you call your command via:

```
bash test.sh
```

bash does not exit, but when you call:

```
bash -o posix test.sh
```

it exits. So either your bash has been compiled to be POSIX compliant by default or you did call a different shell than bash.

See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14 for the standard.

Comment: Spectacular, thank you! So interesting. I was scratching my head for a while on this one.

Comment: Bash, when called with a file called sh, enters posix mode. That is a third possibility and the one that apply here IMO (not compiled, nor other shell).